# Rails, add data to association table by adding custom method to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and I feel this question should have an easy answer but I can't figure it out.

in rails I have two tables USERS and INFOS they have many to many relationship and there is a third table INFOS_USERS but it doesn't have the model.

my problem is I want to add to this association table from Info view, but I have no method to call in the controller!

should I create a new model and controller?
is it possible to add a custom methods to controller?

Thanks

edit: I can write to table from controller but problem is I don't have any controller for the association table so I don't have any method to call from view.

Comment: It's better to add a new association model. `InfoUser`. or a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation between `Info` and `User`

Comment: the both models have has_and_belongs_to_many. my problem is what method in controller should I call from view?

Comment: You do not need to add a controller for every model. If you want to add `users` to `info`, you can do that in the `infos_controller`, if you want to add `infos` to `user` you can do that in the `users_controller`. You can use the `update` action, since you want to update infos, with users. does this answer your question?

Comment: If you still cannot get the idea. please add some code snippets so that I can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add custom methods (actions) to a controller

Your routes might look like:

```
resources :users do 
  members do 
    get 'infos' # => /users/:id/infos
    post 'add_info' # => /users/:id/infos/add_info
  end
end
```

In this case it might make sense to use nested routes, which means you would have a different controller for the 'infos' - checkout the rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 0):

for adding `@user` to `@info`:

```
@info.users << @user
```

if you need create new `User` from association:

```
@info.users.build
```

and you don't need any extra `Controller`s or `Model`s